# can I upgrade Powershell 4.0 to 5.0 without upgrade WMF 4.0 to 5.0

Tags: windows, powershell

Anyone know if I can upgrade the Powershell 4.0 to 5.0 without WMF (Windows Management Framework) upgrade from 4.0 to 5.0, would that give me problem?

If not, where can I upgrade the Powershell 4.0 to 5.0 without the WMF upgrade?

Please don't ask me the reason for why should I do this. I would like to know if I can and how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the [PowerShell source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/) and build it yourself, and get access to a shell running a newer version than the computer has installed, without doing a WMF uprade.

e.g. I have a Windows 10 VM running PowerShell 5 and a compiled build running PS 6.0.0-alpha.

That's not actually upgrading the version on your computer, it's not replacing the built-in version. And I don't know if you can compile PS 5.0, or how complete and capable the compiled version is.